# Loading a YouTube channel GData errors

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, youtube, youtube-api

So I've been following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGkr0EMxkUg) tutorial on loading your YouTube channel to a `-UItableView` and I always seem to get this error 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well the video description says itself that API has changed and the tutorial won't work anymore. You should look over some other tutorial or visit Youtube API and check it out yourself.

For the Error -

- The video provides the GData Library link which should have the classes you are trying to import and getting error. Make sure you have downloaded it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/detail?name=gdata-objectivec-client-1.12.0.zip&can=2&q=) and added it to your project.
- Next make sure the classes of the library are in the compile sources of your project settings. In Here [image]